# how to get id for update or delete the row from foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, pdo

I successfully fetch the data from database and show in the table. But now I want user can edit the data with click the Button 'Edit'. I google but not get what I want. I want when user click on edit button, One pop up form will show. I want form will get only that row value in which row edit button clicked.

```
<?php
    $sth= $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `user-data` WHERE user_uname = :user_uname");

    $sth->execute(array(


        ':user_uname' => $_SESSION["user_name"]

    ));

    foreach ($sth as $row) {


        $user_id= $row['id'];
        $user_username= $row['user_uname'];
        $user_dname= $row['user_dname'];
        $user_pos= $row['user_pos'];
        $user_year= $row['user_year'];
        $user_cont= $row['user_cont'];



        echo '

    <tr>
        <td data-title="username">'.$user_dname.'</td>
        <td data-title="Place">'.$user_pos.'</td>
        <td data-title="Years">'.$user_year.'</td>
        <td data-title="Content">'.$user_cont.'</td>
        <td data-title="Edit">
            <button type="button"  data-target="#modal-login" data-toggle="modal"  class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>&nbsp;
                Edit
            </button>
        </td>
        <td data-title="Del">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;
                Delete
            </button>
        </td>

    </tr>

    ';
        }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each row you output add a link (make it fancy, a button) that sends the data of that row to the PHP file you want to handle it. Then you simply process the data in that file and output what you need.

```
<a href="edit_row.php?row_id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">Edit</a>
```

This is just to show how you would do that.

Comment: Thank you! but unfortunately this is not working. Also when i add this code instead of button then my pop up window not show.

Comment: also can you please tell me! what we say this topic in programming language if i want to google it?

Comment: The link seem be like this "edit_row.php?row_id=$row[%27id%27]"

Comment: @sheikhhunny I made a mistake and forgot to include the PHP tags so that the code would be interpreted, but i fixed it now. Its just passing information using a query string and then retrieving it using $_GET.

Comment: Hi i add this line in my Code <a href="edit_row.php?row_id='.$row['id'] .'">
But when i try to get value it show some 'undefine' error

$row_id= $_GET['row_id']

Comment: @sheikhhunny I already noted that i made a mistake and forgot to add the PHP tags so $row['id'] would be interpreted and i thought you got it. Anyway, that's how you do it. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For use in the Php continue script

```html
<a href="edit_row.php?row_id='.$row['id'] .'">
```